# Dead code warning

Tags: java, date, scheduling, dead-code

```
while(true){
    try 
    {
        if(Calendar.DATE == X){
            startTask();
        } 
        long delay = timeUntilNextCheck();
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } 
    catch (Throwable t) 
    {

    }
}
```

I have a program that requires a specific task to run on a specific day of the month.
After the task is run (Or if its not that day) the thread sleeps until tomorrow where it will check again.

However, I am getting a Dead code warning because part of the code is only ran on a specific day of the month.

I had a read up on what this warning is and I found that in some cases the compiler doesn't compile dead code. So my question is, will this always be compiled?

Comment: Code that only runs at certain times is not *dead code*.

Comment: For which line is the dead code warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, I am getting a Dead code warning because part of the code is
>   only ran on a specific day of the month.

No, you're getting a dead code warning becase `startTask();` will *never* run. `Calendar.DATE` is an internal index constant of the `Calendar` class with the value 5. To get the current day of the month, use this code: `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Comment: can't  X be  5 ? <!--------------------------->

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: it can be, but apparently it isn't, in this case. And the comparison wouldn't make sense in any case.

Answer (score 7):

Can you tell us what `X` is?

```
if(Calendar.DATE == X)
```

If `X` is some constant representing day of month, this will not work because you are comparing `Calendar.DATE` **constant** with another constant `X`. Let me guess, your code is something like:

```
if(Calendar.DATE == 17)  //run on 17th of every month
```

which translates into:

```
if(5 == 17)  //I see dead code
```

Compiler gives you a hint that this condition will never be satisfied (and might not bother compiling the `if` statement body).

Instead you should test:

```
if(new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.DATE) == 17)
```

Or even better use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). You would be surprised how many mistakes can you make with such a simple code (think: server timezone, daylight saving time...)

Comment: why `new GregorianCalendar()` rather then `Calendar.getInstance()`?

Comment: Tricky question, indeed. I think in some strange universe `Calendar.getInstance()` might return something that isn't `GregorianCalendar`. This is not a problem *per se*, however if this other calendar system does not have a notion of *day of the month* (or even *month* altogether), you would get nasty runtime exception. One of the several flaws of Java date/calendar abstractions. Am I not mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the dead code is the line
    startTask();

If the compiler can detect that this is unreachable, it is probably because X (whatever it is) can never take the same value as `Calendar.DATE`, which is always 5. This is "field number for get and set indicating the day of the month." according to the Javadoc, not the current day of the month, which you could get for example using

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE)
```

You might want to look at something like `java.util.Timer` by the way.

Comment: In my timeUntilNextCheck() method I am creating two calendars (todays and tomorrows) and then calculating the difference between them. Is this good practice or is java timer the way to go?

Comment: With java.util.Timer (or something more sophisticated like Quartz) you can just create a task that will run at a given time in the future, without subtracting dates. The Calendar and related classes in the Java standard library are notoriously awkward to use, so Joda-Time is often preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) and configure CronTrigger that would be far better

Comment: I was just going to comment the same. :)

Comment: -1 Exactly. That's a comment, not an answer. It's a useful comment though.